# Color detection with multiple array return

Tags: arrays, colors, return, detection

I have a problem with color detecting and multiple array returning...
Since i found "Tuple" machine i tried to to find white pixels on black background(yes they were white). I can give you a code which i used so you can imagine what is going on:

```
private Tuple<int[], int[]> Find(Image<Gray, byte> bmp)
    {
        int rows = bmp.Rows;
        int cols = bmp.Cols;
        byte[,,] imgByte = bmp.Data;
        int[] x = new int[10];
        int[] y = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i <= rows;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++)
            {
                if (imgByte[i, j, 0] == 255 && imgByte[i, j, 1] == 255 && imgByte[i, j, 2] == 255)
                {   
                    x[i] = i;
                    y[j] = j;
                }
            }
        }

        return Tuple.Create(x,y);
    }
```

This code is launched by a button :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Image<Gray, byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmp);
        textBox1.Text = Find(img).ToString();
    }
```

Ok the summary is that I need to find those pixels and write them somewhere (textbox or something... nevermind) where "x" is x label and "y" is y label.

This code gives me only an exception that tells me something like that index is outside of the bound of the array...

Last thing is picture which i use: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUWEK.jpg)

Can someone help me with this?.. thx guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
    int[] x = new int[10];
    int[] y = new int[10];
```

to this

```
    int[] x = new int[rows];
    int[] y = new int[cols];
```

Otherwise if you have picture bigger than 10x10 pixels, it ends with OutOfBoundsException.

---

Also you are exceeding it in for cycles, change this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rows;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++)
            {
```

To this

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
```